# how to show a tab bar controller after the login screen is launched?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-3.1.2

This is a view based application.

in delegate.m file I have done like this to launch login screen initially:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [window addSubview:viewController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

  LoginView *loginView=[[LoginView alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];

  [window addSubview:loginView.view];
}
```

By adding the above code I have launched login screen sucessfully, but at the bottom of my login screen I can see a space left out.

How can the tab bar controller get launched after sucessful login?

i have creatd a method called login in my LoginView.m file:

```
-(void)login
{
  if(login)
  {
    TabBarController *tabBarController = [[TabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBarController" bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubView: aTabBarController.view];
  }

    [aTabBarController release];
```

Please help me out of this with the appropriate code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034893/show-a-login-screen-before-a-tab-bar-controller

Comment: you need to accept answers to your previous questions, it is discouraging for people to put effort into answering your questions if you can't be bothered to accept their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create on method in appDelegate like.. and In appDelegate.h you have to create an object like this

UITabBarController *Obj_tabbar;

and then in .m file,

```
-(void) switchToTabbarController    
{    
    Obj_tabbar.delegate = self;
    Obj_tabbar.selectedIndex = 0;
    Tracking_HomeVC *obj = [[Tracking_HomeVC alloc]init];
    [self tabBarController:Obj_tabbar didSelectViewController:obj];
    [self.window addSubview:Obj_tabbar.view];
```

}

// At this point Tracking_HomeVC is the first view controller of the TabbarController. and it will be added on window.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

{

```
    if([tabBarController selectedIndex] == 0)
    {
       //Write your code here to do with the first view controller object.
    }
```

}

and then call it from your LoginView like..

```
-(void)LoginPressed    
{    
     AppAppDelegate *delegate =(AppAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     [delegate switchToTabbarController];    
}
```

Comment: i have done like what u have said, but when am running the application it is showing an error in delegate.M file like TabBar Controller Un declared(first use in this function). can u tell me whare am doing wrong???

Answer (score 1):

Your login view (or it's controller if you have one which it looks like you don't) should tell the appDelegate to swap the RootViewController to be a taBarController. You do NOT want the loginview to be trying to add a tabBar as a child of itself.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is creating a tabbarcontroller like normal in your appdelegate and set it as rootviewcontroller:

```
TOTabBarController *tabBarController = [[TOTabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc3 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *vc2_nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
UINavigationController *vc3_nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc3];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2_nc, vc3_nc, nil];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

//set tabbarcontroller as rootviewcontroller
[[self window] setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Then display the login screen modally (without animation) if the user is not logged in:

```
if (not logged in) {
    UIViewController *lvc_nc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [[[self window] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:lvc_nc animated:NO];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: remember in your loginview controller that you send the message to dismiss the modalview once the person signs in: [self dismissModalView...]

Comment: to dismiss my loginview once after the sucessful login what i need to do can i say[self.view removeFromSuperView] in my method??                  and also what does ModalViewController Mean???

Comment: That is not necessary. It will automatically unload the view when you dismiss it. Inside your loginViewController, write [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; when the person logs in.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: If it worked out for you, you should click on the green checkmark next to my answer or upvote it to accept the answer.